# Unable to download file using FTP, after upload file via PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have written simple PHP code to upload image file. Images are uploading successfully.

Here is my code,

```
mkdir("uploaded images", 0777, true);
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPathNew);
```

but when i download that image, it shows me

`Response:   550 Access is denied. 
Error:  Critical file transfer error`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You create the folder every time?

Comment: What user do you use to connect to your FTP server ?

Comment: No, Folder create only one time.

Comment: I am using FileZilla

Comment: This is likely going to depend on server configuration.  Why use FTP anyway?  There are plenty of better, more secure protocols to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to permissions of the file. The uploaded file is owned by a web server user (such as www-data) and your FTP server runs under different user. While you change permissions on the folder to 0777 (allow everything to everyone), the file doesn't inherit the same permissions.

To fix this, you probably can add `chmod($targetPathNew, 0777)` in your code after the `move_uploaded_file(...)`.

There is a chance though that this won't work due to some stricter server configuration. I'm not going to dive into this as judging by your question you're not very familiar with the Linux permissions (sorry if I'm wrong). You can find some essential information about permissions here, for example - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm